# Broken bar (¦) as OR operator in "The C Programming Language" book

Tags: c

*EDIT: Sorry, I accidentally submitted the question before I was done. Boy, are you guys quick!*

I've been going through the second edition of *The C Programming Language* and noticed that the book uses broken bars instead of pipes. Was this an old notation or are they interchangeable?

[image: program to count lines, words, and characters in input]

Comment: This probably isn't it, but are you sure it isn't just the font?

Comment: That's just the font. What's your question?

Comment: I think it's just a font issue.  It's intended to be the same character (ascii 0x7c).

Comment: For more information, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar#Solid_vertical_bar_vs_broken_bar). The broken and solid vertical bars have gotten more distinguished since the days of that book, but they used to be like the two ways of writing a lowercase "a".

Comment: Those are just vertical bars rendered in an old typewriter font.  You can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar#Solid_vertical_bar_vs_broken_bar)

Comment: That's really interesting and the timeline fits since the second edition is from 1988. Can one of you summarize it and post it as an answer? I'd prefer to accept this explanation rather than just "font problem".

Answer (score 4):

Its a font problem, most of the books show it as broken pipe even though it is the pipe operator

Boolean OR operator. It will set all bits true that are true in either of both values provided.

```
if ( a==0 || b==3 ) 

if any one of these is true the "if" statement will execute because it looks for true or 
false values.
```

Comment: Your example shows the **boolean** OR operator, not the bitwise one. Also, `if` is a decision structure, **not** a loop.

Comment: Edited: thanks for the heads up.